# Convert to Int with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, int, type-conversion

Below LINQ has a few `Convert.ToInt32` methods. But it doesn't work. Referring to the internet, it is used `int.Parse` instead of convert. Still gives error. Please show me a direction to do this.

In below query `tody`'s data type is `DateTime`

```
var ds = (from a in dbSetInvHeader
          join b in dbSetCustomer on a.BusinessEntityID equals b.Id
          join c in dbSetFinancialInfo on b.Id equals c.Id
          where (a.TotalAmount - a.AppliedAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount) > 0
                      && DbFunctions.AddDays(a.InvoiceDate, Convert.ToInt32(c.CreditPeriod)) >= tody
          select new OverDueInvoices
                      {
                          CustomerName = b.Name,
                          InvoiceNo = a.InvoiceNo,
                          InvoiceAmount = a.TotalAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount,
                          DueAmount = (a.TotalAmount - a.AppliedAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount),
                          CreditAmount = a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount,
                          NoOfDays = Convert.ToInt32(DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate))
                      }).ToList();
```

**Update :**

The code is using Entity Framework for above LINQ throws errors:

When using `Convert.ToInt32`:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

When using `int.Parse`:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: What is the error that's being thrown?

Comment: try [EntityFunctions ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I added "UPDATE 1" with more details

Comment: For all I can see, `DbFunctions.DiffDays` is returning a `Nullable<int>` already. What do you expect from the `Convert.ToInt32` method?

Comment: @Lei Yang : All of functions of the provided link has input variable as nullable int. But in my LINQ "dbSetFinancialInfo" has "CreditPeriod" field which is decimal type. It is not possible to change the data type to int, because there are a lot of development already done with existing data type. Like that case we must have to cast the data type in LINQ. Mustn't we?

Comment: @grek40 : Data type of "NoOfDays" is int. can we directly assign nullable<int> to int data type? Shouldn't we need to cast it?

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not know about the Convert.ToInt32 function. There doesn't seem to be a workaround to convert a string to an int in Entity Framework. What you can do is add another column to you object NoOfDaysString

```
public string NoOfDaysString {get; set;}
public string NoOfDays {get { return  Convert.ToInt32(NoOfDaysString); } ;}
```

and rewrite your query as such

```
var ds = (from a in dbSetInvHeader
                  join b in dbSetCustomer on a.BusinessEntityID equals b.Id
                  join c in dbSetFinancialInfo on b.Id equals c.Id
                  where (a.TotalAmount - a.AppliedAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount) > 0
                  && DbFunctions.AddDays(a.InvoiceDate, Convert.ToInt32(c.CreditPeriod)) >= tody
                  select new OverDueInvoices
                  {
                      CustomerName = b.Name,
                      InvoiceNo = a.InvoiceNo,
                      InvoiceAmount = a.TotalAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount,
                      DueAmount = (a.TotalAmount - a.AppliedAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount),
                      CreditAmount = a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount,
                      NoOfDaysString = Convert.ToInt32(DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate))

                  }).ToList();
```

This is the only workaround i can think of for the where statement. Add the CreditPeriod in your object and do the where after the objects are in the memory

```
var ds = (from a in dbSetInvHeader
              join b in dbSetCustomer on a.BusinessEntityID equals b.Id
              join c in dbSetFinancialInfo on b.Id equals c.Id
              where (a.TotalAmount - a.AppliedAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount) > 0
              select new OverDueInvoices
              {
                  CustomerName = b.Name,
                  InvoiceNo = a.InvoiceNo,
                  InvoiceAmount = a.TotalAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount,
                  DueAmount = (a.TotalAmount - a.AppliedAmount - a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount),
                  CreditAmount = a.ApplyToInvoiceCreditAmount,
                  NoOfDaysString = Convert.ToInt32(DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate))
                  CreditPeriod = c.CreditPeriod
              })ToList().Where(t=>Convert.ToInt32(t.CreditPeriod) >= NoOfDays).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually this works as you mentioned. But there is some other cast part in WHERE condition. I try to do the same thing including new property called "intCreditDays". But "The specified type member 'intCreditDays' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported." error occurred.

Comment: have you tried casting it as an int (int?)c.CreditPeriod as @Mikhail Neofitov sugested?

Answer (score 1):

As @LiviuBoboia noted, SQL does not know anything about both `Convert.ToInt32` and `int.Parse` methods and EF could not correctly convert call to this method to sql. Instead of this you can do the simple cast:

```
NoOfDaysString = (int)DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate)
```

this cast will be converted to sql as sql function `CONVERT` and this should work good.

Although, `DbFunctions.DiffDays` returning a `Nullable<int>` or `int?` so it would be better to avoid casting it to `(int)` as you can get `InvalidCastException` while trying to convert `null` to `int`

Comment: `int?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: @grek40 yep, I know. I guess, OP more familiar with this syntactic sugar version, instead of actual name.

Answer (score 0):

`DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate)` is returning a `Nullable<int>`, so instead of `Convert.ToInt32` try one of the following

```
DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate).GetValueOrDefault();
DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate) ?? someIntegerDefaultValue;
DbFunctions.DiffDays(tody, a.InvoiceDate).Value;
```

The first one is for the case where you know the result can be `null` and you want to get a `0` instead for this case. The second is when you want a different default value or compute some more complex replacement and the third is for the case where you know that the result should never ever be null and you are ok to get an exception if it is null.